# Set timeout for message with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that after a user has clicked the button, a message appears and should disappear after 3 seconds. I'm trying to use `useEffect` to enable the timeout, but can't get it working:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

const SectionHeader = (props) => {
const {title, button, link, type} = props;
    const [copy, setCopy] = useState(false)
    const [showMessage, setShowMessage] = useState(true);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setShowMessage(false)
      }, 3000)
    }, [])
    const copyToClipboard = (title) => {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(window.location.href + '#' + title.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "-").replaceAll("'", ""))
        setCopy(true)
    }
    return (
        <div id={title.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "-").replaceAll("'", "")}>
          <b>{title}</b>
          <div onClick={() => copyToClipboard(title)}>Copy to clipboard</div> {copy ? 'copied' : ''}
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<SectionHeader title="Test" />,
document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
```

Comment: There's no conditional rendering based on the `showMessage` variable. It's defined, but only used in the `setTimeout()`, not anywhere else.

Comment: The main issue is the empty dependency array, your useEffect function runs as soon as the component mounts. You also don't have a proper model of how your component is supposed to work; what exactly is the point of `setCopy(true)`, given that you also have a state variable called `showMessage`? Here's how to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/0ph8wogq/

Comment: @ChrisG - that's what I was missing, thanks! If you can post that as an answer, I'll make sure to mark it as so!

Comment: That's ok, this is definitely a [dupe](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+show+message+with+timeout+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` execute the code written in its block only when the website is loaded for the first time or when the dependencies changes.

In your code you have not included any dependencies, so it'll only execute the code wrapped inside its block when the site will load for the first time.

```
 useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setShowMessage(false)
      }, 3000)
    }, [here should be some state which changes when a button got clicked])
```